# What is a good model to forecast a single variable?

Tags: forecasting, excel

Let's say I have the values of a variable x for a time period of 15 years. What is a good statistical model to find the values of this variable for the next 10 years?

How good is excel's forecast function in this regard? Would a simple linear regression with the years (Excel) work if we assume the relationship is linear?

Answer (score 2):

There is no general method which works equally well for all kinds of data.  Your task will be to find a model which is a good match for the time period you have.  I would start by exploring the data, starting with plotting $x$ against time.  Maybe looking into standard time series models would be a reasonable next step?

Using simple linear regression with the year as input and $x$ as response corresponds to fitting a linear trend to the data.  This may work well, if the plot I suggested above looks approximately like a straight line.